# REST not working on ColdFusion

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I feel like I must be missing something obvious because the REST documentation seems so simple and the code I produced appears to work correctly unless I try to access it via REST.

**hello.cfc:**

```
component rest="true" restpath="restTest"{
    remote string function sayHello() httpMethod="get"{
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**Service Mapping:**

I have tried both default yes and no with no change.

[image: CFIDE Service Mapping]

**Test Page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>REST Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Calling service as an object:<br>
    <cfset restTest = new hello() />
    <cfdump var="#restTest.sayHello()#" />
    <br>

    Calling service via http:<br>
    <cfhttp url="http://localhost/rest/restTest" result="restResult" method="GET" />
    <cfdump var="#restResult#" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Results:**

[image: REST result]

Comment: There are issues on CF10 and CF11 that aren't going to be fixed with REST. Not sure how 2016 works yet. But I'd just move to Taffy. It's quite easy and works.

Comment: We are using CF10 and upgrading to 2016 eventually and it's not something we can move away from. If I had my way, we wouldn't be using ColdFusion at all.

Comment: Can you log a bug at https://bugbase.adobe.com/ and we will look at it.

Comment: You wouldn't be moving away ColdFusion for Taffy. It's a ColdFusion library/framework.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report. Moving to a framework while there is an underlying issue may compound the problem. It would be better to solve this issue before we start adding other layers that could complicate debugging. I have been experimenting with ColdBox for some time now and may be implementing it with a new build of the project, but I work best knowing how things under the hood work in order to troubleshoot problems more efficiently.

Comment: Adding Taffy or ColdBox frameworks will not compound the problem since they do not use ACF's REST service underneath.

Comment: Just by curiosity, what is the Operating system here? @WaynePorter

Comment: Fedora 22. Our test server is similar but I'm not sure what version of Fedora it is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing without directing the call through a connector/webserver?
Keep your project inside /cfusion/wwwroot/ and then try accessing it via browser
http://localhost:8500/rest/restTest

Sample test also worked for me after changing the URL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Boh.jpg)

Comment: Test page also worked for me , though I din't try with a connector configured. I used "http://localhost:8500/rest/restTest" as URL.

I assume there can some issue with your connector configuration. Please try without connector/webserver and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried many different ways to access the URL, including via curl, wget and directly in multiple browser's address bars. It always comes back with "204 No Content".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a wrong URL when making HTTP request to the REST service. The URL should be like this:

`http://{domain}/rest/{service mapping name}/{component level rest path}/{function level restpath}`

So in your case the correct URL should be:

`http://localhost/rest/api/restTest`

For more info read this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html

Comment: That link is what I used to learn about and write the code I did. As another user suggested, the URL I used should be correct since I set it as the default application. With it set to default, the URL you suggest returns a 404 error. If I switch it to no longer be the default, it gives me the 204 response as before.